# Which is the better approach to launch Heavy Task from MVC .NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, windows-services, task

The scenario is a SQL Server that has to be updated regularly with data obtained from some API calls. Each request to the API may take about 30-200 minutes so they are not instant, and it has to be always asking the API for the new data.
The calls to the API are performed with some input parameters the user of the MVC App(like dates or names)
I was thinking in doing it as a Windows Service, that is launched/stopped from the MVC, but i don´'t know if it is the best approach, cause i don't know if they can easely communicate.
An better approach will be like a Task Item that can perform heavy operations and communicate with the mvc directly. It would be so useful to see a log.
What you, experts, would recommend?
Thanks

Comment: Don't get me wrong, the question is somewhat abstract. Think about it 30-200 minutes is exorbitant. May be the code which does that is not in your control. Communication can be set and there are a number of approaches for it, one is to use the messaging, RabbitMQ or MSMQ. But this will still not hold good as you would need to fix the 30-200 part.

Comment: The request takes too much time because the API has to generate a 1 GB JSON, that has to be parsed and imported to SQL Server. It can't be faster

Answer (score 0):

I would use a windows service and execute a command from the website. It's quite easy:

MVC
sth like

```
    using System.ServiceProcess;        
    ...
    public ActionResult Update()
    {
        int updateCommandId = 1; //example
        ServiceController sc = new ServiceController("windowsServiceName");
        sc.ExecuteCommand(updateCommandId);

    }
```

and for your windows service just override OnCustomCommand:

```
    protected override void OnCustomCommand(int commandId)
    {
         if(commandId == 1) 
         {
          //do your update
         }
    }
```